# Concatenate multiple cells in row into one cell with sep = ">"

Tags: r

I would like to concatenate the last three columns into a new one with a sep = ">" between all names. I have a df:

```
    1   2      3      4     5  
    70  54895  Den    Bas   Tom
    49  45975  John   River Max
    34  30295  Daen   Bob   Jimmy
    19  11995  Morgan Dylan Martin
```

Into

```
    1   2      3  
    70  54895  Den > Bas > Tom
```

Since some rows have multiple columns (198 at max), I can't just type out the column names "3", "4", "5", to concatenate those.

I tried to fix the problem by:

```
df$Names <- paste(df[, 3], sep = ">")
```

Comment: What do you mean multiple columns? If this is a data frame then the number of columns is fixed?

Comment: Some rows only have column 3, 4, and 5 filled. Other rows have column 3 until 144 filled. At maximum, there is one row with 198 columns filled.

Comment: Try `df$Names <- apply(df[, 3:5], 1, paste, collapse = " > ")`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Didn't see your comment, should I delete my answer?

Comment: probably it also needs to remove `NA`'s or blanks whatever OP has in their data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No - looks like a good answer to me!  Great minds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `apply` for one base R option:

```
df$Names <- apply(df[, 3:5], 1, function(x) {
                paste(ifelse(is.na(x), "-", x), collapse = " > ")
            })
```

The above would display `-` for those names which happen to be `NA`.

If instead you don't want to see `NA` values at all, then use:

```
df$Names <- apply(df[, 3:5], 1, function(x) {
                paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " > ")
            })
```

Comment: Great! Now I get Den > Bas > Tom> - > - > - > etc. Hence I prefer to have for those with NA only Den > Bas > Tom